# Why does the admin copy of the newly populated docusign form (through the api endpoint) show as blank?

Tags: docusignapi

I have basically configured the envelope to take in inputs from a portal i created and send that to docusign via the api to populate the field textboxes that i have premade in a template on docusign. I have set up on docusign for that newly populated template to also be sent as a copy to an admin.

The issue is that this copy seems to always be blank, while the recipient copy seems to be working as expected by getting populated according to the envelope I created and sent via the api.

I don't quite know if this is something that can be unlocked w/ a paid account or what the issue is. Appreciate any input on a possible solution.

THE GOAL is to have a similar copy of the agreement w/ populated textboxes to be sent to both admin and recipient.

I tried changing the template settings but nothing works. Do i need to change the envelope?
edit- heres some code

````
envelope_definition = {
                    "status": "sent",
                    "templateId": template_id, #guid #sql############
                     "templateRoles": [
                        {
                            "email": recipientEmail,
                            "name": companyName,
                            "roleName": "signer",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [ 
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "company_name",
                                        "value": companyName
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel":"recipient_email",
                                        "value": recipientEmail 
                                    }
                                 ]```


edit-2 
I have changed it to all have pre-fill tabs except sign date and signature, and with the same data labels as previous sender tabs. do i have to change the envelope definition also?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7kph.png


edit-3 how will this envelope definition change if I use pre fill tabs

   
envelope_definition = {
                    "status": "sent",
                    "templateId": template_id, #guid #sql############
                     "templateRoles": [
                        {
                            "email": recipientEmail,
                            "name": companyName,
                            "roleName": "signer",
                            "tabs": {
                              
                                "textTabs": [ #https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/prefilled-tabs/
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "company_name",
                                        "value": companyName  # Replace with the desired value
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "recipient_email",
                                        "value": recipientEmail  # Replace with the desired value
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "recipient_by",
                                        "value": recipientby  # Replace with the desired value
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "recipient_title",
                                        "value": recipientTitle  # Replace with the desired value
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "date_c,
                                        "value": currDate  # Replace with the desired value
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "recipient_name",
                                        "value": recipientName  # Replace with the desired value
                                    }
                                ]
                            
                                  
                            }
                        }
                        
                    ]
                }
````

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: sure i just have a basic envelope definition. I used
envelope_definition = {
                    "status": "sent",
                    "templateId": template_id, #guid #sql############
                     "templateRoles": [
                        {
                            "email": recipientEmail,
                            "name": companyName,
                            "roleName": "signer",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [

Comment: @InbarGazit just edited the post w code.

Comment: Do you have a template "template_id, #guid #sql############" and is this template with a roleName called "Signer" and do the text tabs in it has the same tab labels you have here? can you triple check everything?

Comment: @InbarGazit yes that's right! template id is the one for the template on docusign, and it is in fact called as signer. text tabs are also the same (actually there are more but for the sake of keeping it simple i provided just two). the workflow works end to end. the only thing i cant figure out is why the admin copy is blank (this seems to be an option on docusign templates).

Comment: what is "admin copy" is that a CC recipient you send this to? what is the routing_order of the recipients?

Comment: yes cc recipient. it is set for the admin role. no routing order @InbarGazit

Comment: Try to make the CC recipient order routing 2 and the signer routing 1

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that if both recipients (Signer and CC) have the same routing order (or have no routing order) than the CC recipients gets the document before it was acted on by the Signer. They should get it again when it's signed by the signer and it should be good at that point, but the first one is sent right away because you didn't specify routing order.

Routing order tells DocuSign the correct order of which recipients to route to in which order. If two recipients has the same routing order (or none is specified) then they get it at the same time.

Comment: The cc copy needs to contain the populated fields which it is not right now. I want it to be so it shouldn't matter if the signer has acted on the document or not. The point is for cc to also have basically the same everything in that copy as the one sent to signer, only difference being lack of actual signature(idk if that makes sense). @InbarGazit

Comment: Make CC routingOrder 2 and signer routingOrder 1, that should do it

Comment: You can't do what you want with a template I think, there's a feature called pre-filled tabs that are not assigned to a recipient so that they can be filled before any recipient gets the envelope

Comment: I have changed it to all have pre-fill tabs except sign date and signature, and with the same data labels as previous sender tabs. do i have to change the envelope definition also? please see edit 2 for image

Comment: So, you want the CC to see the document BEFORE it was signed and then see it again AFTER it was signed? and you want the data to show both times? I am still not clear on what you want to happen exactly

Comment: yes cc needs to see the document and then also get a final copy after signed

Comment: the text tabs are read only? or do the signer can change them? If the signer can change them, then what is the point of the CC seeing them BEFORE signed?

Comment: basically a carbon copy of the document that has been populated with fields will need to go to both signer and admin(cc), only differnece being that admin cannot sign and will have that blank. only the signer can sign and when tehy do and i refresh the admin cc, that should also update with signature and then say that the document is complete.

Comment: text tabs are read only i think, signer cannot change. its fixed in place

Comment: Then why use tabs? You should use Document Generation feature instead

Comment: With document generation you can have a template with fields that can be modified dynamically and then it's part of the document

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-document-generation/

Comment: what does that do

Comment: You put things like {{Field1}} in your document and it's replaced with the value from your code before it's sent out

Comment: so your saying basically send the document contents itsself as part of the envelope definition?

Comment: i see, thats gonna be difficult because the template document is basically made by legal dept. can't really be changed and so i cant rely on that

Comment: Then your other option is to use pre-fill tabs, but not sure they can be used with a template, may need to do this without a template if that's the requirement

Comment: oh okay can you look at edit 3. so there isn't a way i can fill the pre fill tabs the same way as i would regular tabs? feel like that should be possible or else whats that point of that feature in the api

Comment: I can't find edit 3, please read this https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-customize-your-envelopes-pre-fill-fields

Comment: i think you may have to scroll down a little to see it. I am a little confused. The prefill tabs are present right now on the template with the same data labels . how do i change the envelope definition according to this. im not sure if the signer role part still has to stay in the definition or not because this might be causing the issues because the fields on docusign seem to be specific to signer therefore only letting the signer see the populated fields.

Comment: Can't use a template and pre-fill tabs together. You will have to just create the envelope from the API directly, no template

Answer (score 0):

esign lack the functinality for aome reason. only way is to create cc fields and write to those also so it appears for cc rec.